# Laravel test response with The given data was invalid

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, automated-tests

I'm doing unit test with laravel, so I called controller function and I get like a respnse an array
I have been response with this

```
return back()->with('success', 'Lots was generated')
```

and

```
return $this->lots_available;
```

The test give me as response this:

> There was 1 error:
>
> 1. Tests\Feature\LotTest::test_lots
>      Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException: The given data was invalid.

I don't understand the reazon to this response, I'm beginning with the test

This is my function test

```
public function test_lots()  
{    
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();  

    $product = factory(Product::class)->create([
        'size' => 20
    ]);

    $lots = factory(Lot::class, 10)->create([
        'product_id' => $product->id,
    ]);

    $admin = factory(User::class)->create([
        'role_id' => 3
    ]);

    $client_request = 500;

    $this->actingAs($admin)
    ->post(route('lots.distribution'), [$product, $client_request])
    ->assertStatus(200);
}
```

And this my called method

```
public function distribute(ProductRequest $product, $client_order)
{
    $this->lots = $product->lots;  
    $this->client_order = $client_order;  
    $this->getLotAvailable();

    return $this->lots_available;  
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the validation inside `ProductRequest` ?

Comment: By the way `Console.log($client_order);` this is javascript. It will throw an error once the validation succeed.

Comment: @cbaconnier this is the validation
class ProductRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules() {
        return [
            'title' => 'required|unique:products|max:255',
            'sap_id' => 'required|unique:products|max:255'
        ];
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your route is something like `Route::post('/distribute/{product}/{client_order}')`

`route('lots.distribution')` needs the parameters inside the function call

```
route('lots.distribution', [$product, $client_request])
```

Then you need to send the data that passes your rules in `ProductRequest` *otherwise you will get a **validation error**. If you try a `dd(session('errors'))` after the post, you will probably see errors about missing fields.*

```
->post(
    route('lots.distribution', [$product, $client_request]), 
    ['title => 'unique_title', 'sap_id' => 'unique_id']
)
```

Finally in your method, I'm assuming that the request ProductRequest is different than the Model Product:

`public function distribute(ProductRequest $request, Product $product, $client_order)`

Comment: this is the route   
`Route::post('/lot-distribution', 'Front\LotController@distribute')->name('lots.distribution');`

Answer (score 0):

Put the response in a variable and use `dd()` to print it.

You will find it on the `messages` method.
Worked for me.

```
dd($response);
```